# how to determine whether that extension is for an audio type?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I have a string contain filename + ext like: `var s = "blabla.mp3"`.

How to find out if the string contain file ext that matches for audio type?
mp3, mp4....

```
var s = 'blabla.mp3';
function isAudioType(s) { return true/false; }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the file extension, or how to determine whether that extension is for an audio type (according to that machine's current settings)?

Comment: how to determine whether that extension is for an audio type?

Comment: Create a list of extensions you accept to be audio and check if that file's extension is in the list.

Comment: What is the use case? Checking for the extension or filename in general is **really** unsafe

Comment: Please use the edit link to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using regex:

```
function isAudioType(s) { 
  return /\.(mp3|mp4)$/i.test(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function which matches the target file name's extension against a list of desired extensions you want to check.

```js
function isAudioType(s) { 
    var audioTypes = [".mp3", ".wav"], // Add as many extensions you like here...
        audioExt = s.replace(/^.+(?=\.)/i, '');

    return (audioTypes.indexOf(audioExt.toLowerCase()) > -1); 
}

console.log(isAudioType('blabla.mp3'));
console.log(isAudioType('blabla.jpg'));
```

Comment: some missing: `.adp`, `.au`, `.snd`,`.mid`, `.midi`, `.kar`, `.rmi`, `.m4a`, `.mp4a`, `.mpga`, `.mpg2`, `.mp2`, `.mp2a` `.m2a` `.m3a`, `.oga`, `.spx`, `.s3m`, `.sil`, `.uva` [many others quite rare...], `.weba`, `.aac`, `.aif` `.aiff`, `.aifc`, `.flac`, `.mka`, `.wax`, `.wma`, `.rma`, `.ra`, `.rmp`, `.wav`, `.xm`. Some problematic since not only audio (some are in your list) `.ogg`, `.mp4`, `.webm`, `.mov` (probably more).

Comment: @Kaiido - I think DontVoteMeDown was just showing *how*, not providing an exhaustive list of extensions. But as you said, extensions aren't a reliable way to know the file type anyway... :-) Good point about container formats that aren't just audio.

Comment: Yes, and what this comment tries to convey is that even checking for "is this extension one of an audio type" is not as easy as just a 4 items array lookup.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the input. As TJ said, it was just an example, I'm not supose to tell OP's what extensions he should use or not. It's not part of the question I think.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can add as many cases as you want. In this example I added the mp3 case only. You could add mp4 and others too, using a switch for example.

```
var s = 'blabla.mp3';

function isAudio (fileName) {
    let arr = fileName.split('.');

    if (arr[arr.length-1] === 'mp3'){
        return true;
    }

}

console.log(isAudio(s));
```